# Where can I find the implementation of cblas_sgemm() function in OpenBlas project?

Tags: openblas

I find cblas_sgemm() was declared in `cblas.h`,but I cannot find the implementation of it.Which file contains the implementation of `cblas_sgemm`or `cblas.h`?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: I use `ubuntu/linux`operating system running on PC which has `x86_64`architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find all cblas definitions here:

`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/cblas-openblas.h`